# Only "Vulnerable" Flash Player version works

Tags: 12.10, firefox, lubuntu, flash

For the last year, I have been using outdated Shockwave Flash 11.1 r102 in Firefox, because more recent versions (11.2 r202.243 or .280) don't work for me. Typically, with r202 versions, I get blanks instead of Streetview images & YouTube videos. Chromium seems to use whatever flash player I install in FF and its behavior follows FF.

Recently, I started to get awful red warnings about r102 being "vulnerable" (which I believe, of course) & it is disabled & I have to activate it manually every time I want to use it on the above sites.

So in the last few days, I have tried r202 versions again, but they still don't work.
I am currently using Lubuntu 12.10 with FF20.0, but I have the same behavior with the same versions of flashplayer in Ubuntu 10.04.

Can I expect any versions to work "normally" in Ubuntu?

Comment: Not likely. Have you tried using the versions in the repository instead of installing it yourself? Are you 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I am using 32 bit.

The r102 version which works (but is vulnerable) was obtained by copy-pasting from my 10.04LTS back-up system last year.
I obtained r202.243 & r202.280 versions by temporarily installing Flashplugin-installer via Synaptic, then copy-pasting the libflashplayer.so file from /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer to a "safe" folder, then uninstalling flashplugin-installer, then copy-pasting the .so file to /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins.
To get r202.243, I had to force the version.

So now I have 3 different .so files I can copy/paste into ../mozilla plugins as I like.

Comment: I have tried various other methods, like Flash-Aid 2.2.3 (installed but currently disabled), installing flashplugin-installer normally, & following Adobe links, but with rubbish results.

I am happy to try any other (preferably GUI) suggestions.

To repeat my question - should I expect to be able to see YouTube videos & Streetview images in 12.10?
I expect so, but nobody actually said so...

Thanks

Comment: Well - I have Lubuntu 12.04 on a netbook with Firefox 19.0 & that works OK for Streetview & for YouTube.
So that answers my question "should it work?"
The flash setup there is Flashplugin-installer 11.2.202.270ubuntu12.04.1 & libflashplayer.so is in /usr/lib/flashplayer-installer with links via /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins & /etc/alternatives/mozilla-flashplayer.

I tried again to recreate that setup on my troublesome 12.10 Lubuntu, by removing existing libflashplayer.so files & installing flashplugin-installer via Synapt, but that takes me back to no Streetview images etc.

Comment: Seems to be a well known year-old Adobe Bug with no fix: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3161034

Answer (score 0):

I have just downloaded the latest tar.gz file for 64bit linux from adobe.com (version 11.2.202.280). It seems to me that firefox takes the file from /usr/share/ubufox/plugins/, where libflashplayer.so is a symlink to /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so.
So I have unpacked the package, and copied libflashplayer.so to /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/. After restarting firefox, the flash plugin works, it no longer complains.
I use Ubuntu 12.04, and I have flashplugin64-installer installed, but I think it does not matter as long as you can find the location of the old plugin.
Good Luck!